# Why My Python Random's seed doesn't Work?

Tags: python, python-2.7, random

I am trying to implement an algorithm, and I build a class for it:

```
class Ksampler:

    def __init__(self, K,N,L0):

        self.M31=2147483647
        self.L0=L0
        self.N=N
        self.error=self.prob=float(1)/N
        self.LNUM  =31
        self.K=self.t=K
        self.M61 = 2305843009213693951
        self.Kmax=5*self.K
        self.n=pow(2,31)
        print 'k=',self.K,'l=',self.LNUM
        rn.seed()
        self.r=[int(rn.uniform(0,self.M61-1)) for i in range(self.t)]

        ......
```

Then I build many instances:

```
for i in range(100):
    sam[i]=Ksampler(5,100,100)
    sam[i].prin()
```

But my output is wrong, so I print the random numbers:

```
def prin(self):
    print self.r
```

When I call this function, I found these 100 random numbers are just 10 or 9 groups of random numbers, not 100 groups.
For example, those 4 groups random numbers are just the same one!

```
[2193020450880616192, 2067278345537971968, 1594906683693397504,     2120708475826965504, 756774356426756096]
[2193020450880616192, 2067278345537971968, 1594906683693397504, 2120708475826965504, 756774356426756096]
[2193020450880616192, 2067278345537971968, 1594906683693397504, 2120708475826965504, 756774356426756096]
[2193020450880616192, 2067278345537971968, 1594906683693397504, 2120708475826965504, 756774356426756096]
```

Why does this happen?  I use `rn.seed()` when each instance is initialized.

Comment: Probably because it's seeded with the current time and your init is so fast, that there is not enough time inbetween calls. I would recommend introducing something like a static variable, so that each class is initialized with a growing number. (This is not perfect in some scenarios in regards to some PRNGS; google distributed seeding)

Comment: Thank you, I have thought this circumstance, so you can see that in the for loop that used to generate instances, I try to use rn.seed(i), but this does not work.

Comment: Why seed at all? `random` does it for you automatically -- and it doesn't do it too much.

Comment: Show the actual printing. Looks like you print `r` from the same instance again and again.

Comment: If your constructor still has `rn.seed()` in it, the fact that you had `rn.seed(i)` before a call to the constructor isn't relevant.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Search for all calls to `rn.seed()`. Maybe you have a `rn.seed(number)` somewhere and produce the same random numbers for each instance.

Comment: Thank you all. I will try it again to see the problem.

Comment: I also can't reproduce your problem. Perhaps you are printing aliases for the same object.